# understand output and format of `udevadm info /dev/sda1`

Tags: udev, sysfs

Last time I was responsible for a unix system it was AT&T many years ago. I've finally got unix (linux) at home again. Things have changed.

I'm working on understanding udev and /sys.

The output format using `--attribute-walk` is most widely doc'd/referenced. I've been unable to find

1. description of raw/plain database output

   - In particular, meaning of `P:`, `N:`, `L:`, `S:`, `E:`
   - Is there a description of the keys or how they are derived
2. understanding the difference/mapping between database entries and udev rule format
3. description/understanding of the /sys directory structure

I'm picking up stuff, but there are gaping holes. Any information and especially good links appreciated.

Comment: Guess: P = path in /sys, N = name, S = symlink, E = environment variable. Environment variables are derived in multiple ways, e.g. through `blkid` for harddisks. There's kernel documentation about the `/sys` directory structure. No, I don't know any resource that explains all that pre-digested on a single page. Would be nice to have one.